# SQL - Oracle - Group with Members in Common

Tags: sql, oracle

List student groups that have at least two members in common

```
select a.studentid, a.groupid
from membersof a
join (
  select studentid, groupid
  from membersof 
  group by groupid
  where count(studentid) >= 2) b on a.studentid = b.studentid
where a.studentid = b.studentid
```

I don't think I'm quite getting this correctly but basically, I need to find the groupID that has at least two members in common.  With the query above I keep getting a "missing right parenthesis error, but I closed the join and the count, any help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use HAVING when comparing aggregation columns.

```
  select studentid, groupid
  from membersof 
  group by groupid
  HAVING count(studentid) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want pairs of groups, joined by students and then aggregated for the count:

```
select m1.groupid, m2.groupid
from membersof m1 join
     membersof m2
     on m1.studentid = m2.studentid and m1.groupid < m2.groupid
group by m1.groupid, m2.groupid
having count(*) >= 2;
```